# executing a service after another service has been started

Tags: bash, scripting, shell

i have installed MySQL NDB cluster. It needs around 2-3 minutes to synchronise the database in between cluster nodes. Once the synchronisation finished only, I can start another application called heartbeat. Therefore in my shell script, I want to check the availability of the ndbd service all the times. Once this service become available, I need to start the heartbeat application in five minute time. Could you please help me to write the script.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using the "wait" bash built-in command.

From "man bash"

> wait [n]
>
> Wait for the specified process and return its termination status.  n may
>   be a process ID or a job
>   specification; if a job spec is given,
>   all processes  in  that  job’s 
>   pipeline are waited for.  If n is not
>   given, all currently active child
>   processes are waited for, and the
>   return status is zero.  If n specifies
>   a non-existent process or job, the
>   return status is 127.  Otherwise, the
>   return status is the exit status of
>   the last process or job waited for.

You script could look something like this:

```
# send to background
./ndb_startup_script & 

# wait on pid of ndb_startup_script
wait $!

if [ $? -eq 0 ] # assuming 0 is ret code for successful run
then 
    ./heartbeat_startup_script
else 
    # extra stuff to handle error
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd to is have the ndb script exec another script, so that it's not waiting for the 5 minutes to finish and blocking other services from starting.

```
## whatever starts ndb
exec heartbeat_startup_script
```

I've put a sleep 300 (seconds) in here, cause you've specified 5 minutes, but checking if the ndb sync is done would be much better.

```
##heartbeat_startup_script
sleep 300
heartbeat
```